# Let G be a group. If H is a normal subgroup in G, and K is a normal subgroup of H, when is K a normal subgroup of G?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know that K is normal in G iff K is characteristic in H. However how can you prove this, and how do you show that K is normal in H is not sufficient for K to be normal in G?

Comment: You construct an explicit example for the second part.

Comment: That's the thing; I'm struggling to find a concrete example because I don't know how to check if a normal subgroup is characteristic

Comment: Your first sentence is false.  The reverse direction is true, but in general $K$ need not be characteristic in $H$ to be normal in $G$.

Comment: Oh I see, so that's merely a sufficient condition... Right I have some thinking to do!

Comment: As zibadawa says: for $K$ to be normal in $H$, it suffices for $K$ to be setwise invariant under the automorphisms *in the image of* $G\to{\rm Aut}(H)$, so if this image is proper, then in principle $K$ need not be characteristic in $H$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G=A_4, H=\{(1\;2)(3\;4),(1\;3)(2\;4),(1\;4)(2\;3),e\}, K=\{e, (1\;2)(3\;4)\}$. Then $H$ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is normal in $H$. But $K$ is not normal in $G$.

Answer (score 3):

There are some cases where normality is transitive. Let $\;K\lhd H\lhd G\;$ , then $\;K\lhd G\; $ if

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;K\,\text{char.}\,\\
(2)&\;\; H\;\;\text{is cyclic}\\
(3)&\;\;H\;\;\text{is a direct factor of}\;\;G\end{align*}$$

Groups in which normality is transitive are called $\;T$-groups, and there's a reasonably wide literature on this.

Comment: A generalization of (3) is $G=HC_G(H)$. This happens a bit more often in $p$-groups.